# Can I live in Bulgaria with a residence permit from Spain?

Tags: european-union, passport, schengen

US citizen here.  My answer to my own question leads towards "no". No harm in asking.

I have means to obtain a residence permit in Spain.

Can I then over stay my 90/180 day visa free stay my US passport enables in Bulgaria?

Assume for answering the question that Bulgaria never becomes part of Schengen.

Thanks

Comment: Your residence permit for Spain allows you to reside in Spain. It does not allow you to overstay the 90 days in the other Schengen countries **or** the seperate 90 days for Bulgaria, Romania and Cyprus.